# How to ignore subquery result if it's empty

Tags: mariadb, subquery

I have the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS amount FROM `sensors` WHERE occurred_at >= (
  SELECT MAX(CONVERT(performed_at, DATETIME)) AS date FROM `maintenance` WHERE id = 1
);
```

Which get me all `sensors` who 'occurred_at' after the date returned by the subquery `SELECT MAX(CONVERT(performed_at, DATETIME)) AS date FROM maintenance WHERE id = 1`, its working like a charm.

The issue is if the sub-query return an empty value (such as no `maintenance` where declared), So I would like to ignore the subquery if no `maintenance` entries where found.

I currently find a working solution using `COALESCE()` and the first timestamp, but I'm wondering if no better way does exist:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS amount FROM `sensors` WHERE occurred_at >= COALESCE(
  (SELECT CONVERT(max(performed_at), DATETIME) AS date FROM `maintenance` WHERE id = 1),
  '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
)
AND is_deleted IS FALSE AND type = 'occurrence';
```